# How do I calculate the location of the selectedText with a LiveCode field?

Tags: ios, user-experience, livecode

I want to scroll the field so the selection is visible after resizing it. To do that I need to calculate the height from the top of the field that the selection is and then offset the current scroll to work out the new scroll. I can't assume a fixedLineHeight. Anyone have any clues?

Comment: Gian thanks for the edit but this isn't iOS specific. LiveCode is cross platform. Unfortunately there's no LiveCode tag yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some searching in the dictionary I found the selectedLoc function. I ended up with the following code executed after each resize of the field which gives the behavior I wanted.

```
   put item 2 of the selectedLoc-the scroll of pField into tSelectionHeight
   if tSelectionHeight > the scroll of pField+the height of pField then
      set the scroll of pField to tSelectionHeight-the height of pField
   end if
```

Answer (score 1):

In the event there's no selected location, the following also works. I use this in PowerDebug to center the breakpoint or current line of code in the debug window. (And yes, I realize I'm assuming the lineheight is consistent in the field).

```
command CenterDebugText pLinesToHilite
  local tLineHeight, tFieldHeight
  local tScroll

  lock screen
  set the hilitedlines of field kDebugFieldName of me to pLinesToHilite
  -- center the breakpoint line in the display

  -- calculate the number of visible script lines
  put the effective textheight of field kDebugFieldName into tLineHeight
  put the height of field kDebugFieldName into tFieldHeight

  put tLineHeight * (item 1 of pLinesToHilite) into tScroll
  subtract tFieldHeight / 2 from tScroll
  set the vscroll of field kDebugFieldName to trunc(tScroll)
  unlock screen
end CenterDebugText
```

Comment: Nice technique. Is there no selectedLoc after setting the hilitedLines of a field with listBehavior? I think selectedLines and hilitedLines are almost synonyms (slightly different behavior if the noncontiguousHilites is true).